# Returning a value from another class to Activity in Android

Tags: java, android

HI i have been trying to pass values from android form to php page through json and get the result through JSON i have got an example and implemented it. In that example i am passing username and password entered in android form to php page through json in the page it is retrieving the role of the details passed form database and passing the result to android class  and my function is setting the retrieved value to a text filed and the result is displayed in the particular text field. Now want i want is i want to return the result as a String and retrieve it in MainActivity. I'm pasting the code below. Please help me.

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private EditText usernameField,passwordField,role;
   private TextView status,method;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    usernameField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      passwordField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      role = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

}
public void login(View view){
      String username = usernameField.getText().toString();
      String password = passwordField.getText().toString();
      //method.setText("Get Method");
      new SigninActivity(this,role,0).execute(username,password);

   }
```

SigninActivity.class

```
public class SigninActivity extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
private EditText  roleField;
   private Context context;
   private int byGetOrPost = 0; 
  private static InputStream is;
   //JSONObject jsonParser; 
   public SigninActivity(Context context,EditText roleField,int flag) {
              this.context = context;
              this.roleField = roleField;
              this.is=null;
             // this.jsonParser= new JSONObject();
           }
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        String username = (String)arg0[0];
        String password = (String)arg0[1];
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        String link = "http://Myapp.com/login.php";
        //URL url = new URL(link);
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
        link+= "?" + paramString;
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(link);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();;
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            String json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return sb.toString();
  }catch(Exception e){
     return new String("Exception:-- " + e.getMessage());
  }

}
 protected void onPostExecute(String result){
      this.roleField.setText(result);
   }
```

}

Here the result is retrieved and set to the text filed in `onPostExecute()` function in SigninActivity class itself what i want to do is i want the value to be returned in MainActivity as a String to do further manipulations instead of using a textView

Comment: You can use interface as a callback to the Activity

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple

**Use this for sending in the next activity**

```
resp = new JSONObject(result);

                            JSONObject Login1Result = resp.getJSONObject("LoginResult");
                            String strMessage = Login1Result.getString("EmployeeID");

                        JSONObject status = Login1Result.getJSONObject("status");

                        if (status.getString("message").equalsIgnoreCase("OK"))
                        {


                           Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), next.class);
                           i.putExtra("new_variable_name",strMessage);
                           startActivity(i);
```

**for getting it in next activity**

```
         {
             Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
              String strEmployeeID="";
              if (extras != null)
              {

                  String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");

                  strEmployeeID = value;
              }


             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), nextTonext.class);
             i.putExtra("new_variable_name",strEmployeeID);
             startActivity(i); 
         }
```

Comment: i am not creating a seperate Activity iam creating a java class now as i mentioned above result is obtained in that class how to return that result to MainActivity. I tried this with two Activities it is working

Answer (score 0):

You can try SharedPreferences, it's easy to use and quite powerful [You can find it here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: is there any other way so that i can change few lines of code instead of chaging the total one

Comment: Use tushar narang's method then. But I in my personal opinion i suggest to use Shared Preferences, it seem complicated at first, but indeed is quite simple and you'll not have to replace any line of your code, just add this method

Comment: Can this shared preference stored in one class accessed in another class as in if i store the preference in SiginingActivity class can i access it in MainActivity class?